# Cairo STM32MP1 cairo_surface_write_to_png always returns CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR

Tags: c, linux, gtk, stm32, cairo

I am trying to write a PNG file. I am always getting a write error (`CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR`).

```
    cairo_surface_t *image_surface = cairo_surface_create_similar_image(pBitmap -> mainSurface,
                     CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, pBitmap -> geom.width, pBitmap -> geom.height);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(image_surface);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, pBitmap -> mainSurface, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    cairo_status_t cairo_errCode;

    if(pFile)
    {
        char template[] = "./fileXXXXXX.png";
        char *tempFileName = mkdtemp(template);
        if(tempFileName)
        {
            if((cairo_errCode = cairo_surface_write_to_png(image_surface, tempFileName)) == CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
```

As far as I understand it clearly indicates a file error. I tried many locations to see if it was not a permissions problem.

Comment: Are you aware that `mkdtemp` returns a new temporary directory? Do you mean `mktemp`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri I wanted to use `mkstemp` - thank you very much. Please write the answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: Oops yes, `mktemp` is obsolete, `mkstemp` is a  better option.

Comment: @DavidRanieri stupid typo `'d'` instead of `'s'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mkdtemp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdtemp.html) returns a new temporary directory.

You want [mkstemp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) (a new temporary file).